# Why changing $\liminf$ by $\limsup$?

Tags: measure-theory

In a proof (of the dominated convergence theorem) I found the following:

$$
\liminf_{n\to\infty}\int (2g-h_n)\, d\mu=\int 2g\, d\mu-\limsup_{n\to\infty}\int h_n\, d\mu.
$$

---

I do not understand where the $\limsup_n$ comes from!

To my opinion it is
$$
\liminf_{n\to\infty}\int (2g-h_n)\, d\mu=\lim\inf_{n\to\infty}\int 2g\, d\mu-\liminf_{n\to\infty}\int h_n\, d\mu\\=\int 2g\, d\mu-\liminf_{n\to\infty}\int h_n\, d\mu.
$$

Comment: What are $g$ and $h_n$?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Recall that, for any set $S\subset\mathbb{R}$,
$$\inf(-S)=-\sup(S).$$
(For example, consider $S=\{0,1\}$.)
The negative sign interchanges $\inf$'s and $\sup$'s.

Comment: Is it already false to write $\liminf_n\int (2g-h_n)\, d\mu=\liminf_n\int 2g\, d\mu-\liminf_n\int h_n\, d\mu$? I cannot see how I have to apply that the negative sign changes $\liminf$ and $\limsup$ here.

Comment: Yes, what you have written is incorrect.
$$\liminf_{n\to\infty}\int(2g-h_n)\,d\mu=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\inf_{m\geq n}\int(2g-h_m)\,d\mu\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\inf_{m\geq n}\left(\int 2g\,d\mu-\int h_m\,d\mu\right)\right)$$
so you ultimately have an expression that looks like
$$\inf_{m\geq n}(a-b_m)$$

Comment: And then? Sorry I don't see!

Comment: We have
$$\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\inf_{m\geq n}\left(\int 2g\,d\mu-\int h_m\,d\mu\right)\right)&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\int 2g\,d\mu+\inf_{m\geq n}\left(-\int h_m\,d\mu\right)\right)\\\\
&=\int 2g\,d\mu+\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\inf_{m\geq n}\left(-\int h_m\,d\mu\right)\right)
\end{align*}$$
For each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, define the set
$$S_n=\left\{\int h_m\,d\mu:m\geq n\right\}$$
so that we have
$$\int 2g\,d\mu+\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\inf(-S_n)\right)=\int 2g\,d\mu+\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(-\sup(S_n)\right)=\int 2g\,d\mu-\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\sup(S_n)\right)$$

Comment: Now I see, thank you very much!